# OpenStack cartridge-add gives github could not read username error

Tags: openshift-online-2

I am trying to add a paper trail cartridge to an existing Wildfly 8.2.0 gear with the following command:

```
rhc cartridge-add https://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=openshift-cartridges/openshift-papertrailapp-cartridge -a test
```

I keep running into this error:

```
git clone https://github.com/developercorey/openshift-papertrailapp-cartridge.git papertrailapp
fatal: could not read Username for 'https:// github.com': No such device or address
```

I cant seem to figure out how to remote add this git repo to my gear.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where you are getting the command you are trying to run. If you want to use the `cartreflect` service, then using the documentation found [here](https://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/) I believe the command would be:

`rhc cartridge-add https://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/github/openshift-cartridges/openshift-papertrailapp-cartridge?commit=master&r=1 -a test`

If you just want to install the cartridge directly, then just use the command they give you on the [project's GitHub page](https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-papertrailapp-cartridge):

`rhc cartridge-add https://raw.github.com/developercorey/openshift-papertrailapp-cartridge/master/metadata/manifest.yml -a test`

If you are having trouble then I would recommend reviewing the three `rhc` commands they give you in the [cartridge documentation](https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-papertrailapp-cartridge).